# Angular Guards: Prevent manually accessing a URL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router-guards

We have several routes in our app which are not supposed to be navigated by the user by directly entering their URLs into the browser’s address bar.

Instead we only want to make them accessible when we programmatically navigate using `router.navigate()` through our application logic.

Using Angular’s `CanActivate` guard, is there some flag or attribute which we could use to distinguish between those two cases:

1. Route is being accessed directly as the user typed `/no/direct/access` into the address bar
2. Route is being accessed via `router.navigate(['/', 'no', 'direct', 'access'])` (which might in turn be triggered by a different guard, so `router.navigated` unfortunately doesn’t seem to help here)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found possibility to distinguish between cases you've described. I found a way to prevent manual navigation to route though

You can check `.navigated` property on router. Accordingly to docs it is

> True if at least one navigation event has occurred, false otherwise

```
export class PreventDirectNavigationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
  ) { }
  canActivate(
    _activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): boolean | UrlTree {

    return this._router.navigated;
  }
}
```

Also Angular has navigation trigger flag. From [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L216)

> ```
> Identifies how this navigation was triggered.
>
> imperative - Triggered by `router.navigateByUrl` or `router.navigate`.
> popstate -  Triggered by a popstate event.
> hashchange - Triggered by a hashchange event.
> ```

```
       trigger: 'imperative' | 'popstate' | 'hashchange';
```

Comment: If you manipulate URL your app will be reloaded,and it will be considered as first navigation for angular

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, `router.navigated` is `false` when being redirected from another guard (see point 2 in my question), as there was no “navigation” before :-( Realize that this is an edge-edge case and I’ll probably need to overthink this entirely.